# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 using Spring-Security AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, http, authentication, spring-security

I'm building a RESTful authentication service and I'm having trouble connecting to it. I get the dreaded *"Server returned HTTP response code: 400"* when trying to retrieve the response. This seems very odd. I would think I'd get this error when sending the request.

I'm using this service as part of a Spring-Security AuthenticationProvider. I'm currently using a simulator instead of the actual service for testing. It won't connect to either the simulator or the service.

Here is the calling method:

```
public <T> T invoke(String service, Object request, Class<T> responseType) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/simulator/rest" + service);
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
    uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    uc.setDoOutput(true);
    uc.setDoInput(true);
    uc.connect();

    OutputStream out = uc.getOutputStream();
    mapper.writeValue(out, request);
    out.close();

    return mapper.readValue(uc.getInputStream(), responseType);
}
```

Here is the code that calls this method:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = 
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("thomas", "thomas");
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken response = 
    invoke("/authenticate", token, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
```

Here is the simulator method that gets called:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticate(
    @RequestBody UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userNameAndPassword) {

    String userName = (String) userNameAndPassword.getPrincipal();
    String password = (String) userNameAndPassword.getCredentials();
    if (userName.equalsIgnoreCase("thomas")) {
        if (userName.equals(password)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken response = 
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userName,
                        password, 
                        new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());
                return response;
            }
        }
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password);
    }
```

The line that causes the error is the :

```
mapper.readValue(uc.getInputStream(), responseType);
```

If can't see any issues with this code. Must have been looking at it too long. Need new eyes on the problem.

BTW, this REST service and simulator has been used successfully with other operations.

**Additional Information:**

The error occurs in the uc.getInputStream() call. The HttpURLConnection.inputStream = null.

Also, the headers for the request are as follows:

If this helps, here are the headers for this request:

```
[WARN] 400 - POST /simulator/rest/authenticate (127.0.0.1) 1417 bytes
   Request headers
      Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
      X-Tenant: 1
      Authorization: 0000013770b132a1dfcbfe0a694542b244534e0e406cfa857660c904daa89af91d0ac769
      Cache-Control: no-cache
      Pragma: no-cache
      User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_26
      Host: localhost:8888
      Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
      Connection: keep-alive
      Content-Length: 112
   Response headers
      Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1r02p7yvm8mzs;Path=/
      X-UA-Compatible: IE=9
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
      Content-Length: 1417
```

Here is the my Token code:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public class SerializedAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2783395505630241326L;

    private Object principal;
    private Object credentials;

    /**
     * no-arg constructor to satisfy Serializable.
     */
    public SerializedAuthenticationToken() {
        super(null, null);
    }

    /**
     * constructor.
     */
    public SerializedAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(null, null);
        setPrincipal(principal);
        setCredentials(credentials);
    }

    /**
     * constructor with List<GrantedAuthorities>.
     */
    public SerializedAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(null, null, authorities);
        setPrincipal(principal);
        setCredentials(credentials);
    }

    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }

    public void setPrincipal(Object principal) {
        this.principal = principal;
    }

    public Object getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }

    public void setCredentials(Object credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public void setName(Object name) {

    }
}
```

I also now am getting a new stack trace:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Cannot set this token to trusted - use constructor which takes a GrantedAuthority list instead (through reference chain: com.mckesson.shared.util.SerializedAuthenticationToken["authenticated"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Dummy token to do that. Here is my test to verify it:

```
public class JacksonTest {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("thomas", "thomas");
    String tokenStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(token);
    /* WON'T WORK
     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = mapper.readValue(tokenStr, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
     */
    MyToken auth = mapper.readValue(tokenStr, MyToken.class);
    String authStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(auth);

    Assert.assertThat(tokenStr.equals(authStr), is(true));
}


private static class MyToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private Object principal;
    private Object credentials;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5045038656629236029L;

    public MyToken() {

        super(null, null);
    }

    public MyToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {

        super(null, null);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    /**
     * @return the principal
     */
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }

    /**
     * @param principal the principal to set
     */
    public void setPrincipal(Object principal) {
        this.principal = principal;
    }

    /**
     * @return the credentials
     */
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }

    /**
     * @param credentials the credentials to set
     */
    public void setCredentials(Object credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }


    public void setName(Object name) {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: The actual error occurs in the uc.getInputStream() call in the mapper parameter. On debug, the HttpURLConnection.inputStream is null.

Comment: Is the authenticate method of controller working for other applications? I think you may have to use dummy token in there too so that token object can be constructed from the JSON request: public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticate(
    @RequestBody MyToken userNameAndPassword) { ...}

Comment: I changed it so all references to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken were replaced by my version of MyToken. And no, authenticate() doesn't work for anything at this time.

Comment: I've added the headers for this request in the main question text.

Comment: You have to add boolean authenticated field (and its setter and getter) in you token. I think there is no need to extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. You can use a simple POJO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can't spot the exact issue, but I think a contributor to the problem is that fact that you're unnecessarily dropping down to such a low-level API to accomplish something for which some very reasonable abstractions exist.  Have a look at Spring's RestTemplate to see a more elegant means or writing client code against a RESTful service.  Whatever you're doing wrong, chances are RestTemplate will get it right.

Comment: I'll look into the RestTemplate. Thanks.

Comment: When I use the RestTemplate, I get a very similar error message: HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request. So, this isn't fixing anything.